# Libgdx Particle2D looking weird

Tags: java, libgdx, particles

I have a little application and inserted a particle. Everything is fine, but the Particle is stretched or at least looking weird. This should be a simple call, but i did not find an answer yet.

Particle in Particle Editor looks good, in App looks not good.

Loading Code

```
    Gdx.app.setLogLevel(Application.LOG_DEBUG);
    app.getAssets().getLogger().setLevel(Application.LOG_DEBUG);
    Gdx.app.log("MyTag", "my informative message");

    app.getAssets().load("badlogic.jpg",Texture.class);
    app.getAssets().load("uiskin.json",Skin.class);
    app.getAssets().load("particle1.p", ParticleEffect.class);
    app.getAssets().load("particle2.p", ParticleEffect.class);
```

Init code

```
ParticleEffect effect;
SpriteBatch batch;

    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    effect = app.getAssets().get("particle2.p", ParticleEffect.class);
    //Setting the position of the ParticleEffect
    effect.setPosition(100, 100);
    effect.start();
```

Render code

```
    batch.begin();
    //Updating and Drawing the particle effect
    effect.draw(batch, delta);
    batch.end();;
    if(effect.isComplete()){
        effect.reset();
    }
```

Camera

```
    app.V_WIDTH = width;
    app.V_HEIGHT = height;
    app.getCamera().setToOrtho(false, app.V_WIDTH, app.V_HEIGHT);
    stage.getViewport().update(width, height, true);
```

[image: Particle how it should look]

Comment: It looks like it's using the entire atlas Texture instead of a region of the texture. Can you show how you're loading it?

Comment: just plain loading with assesmanager a file that is created by particle editor. Any more advise?

Comment: Log `effect.getEmitters().first().getImagePath()` and see if it matches the image file you designed if for.

Comment: thanks. i guess i have a ugly image. what .png do i need to get the same effect as the particle editor?

Comment: The default particle image is here: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/libgdx/libgdx/master/extensions/gdx-tools/assets/particle.png Put it next to your .p file in your assets.

Comment: Normally, you open your own image file in the particle editor, and when you save, that file's name is saved into your .p file. Then you place a copy of that images in your assets directory next to the .p file (or you put the image into your texture atlas, and pass the atlas in a TextureLoaderParameter to the AssetManager).

Comment: thank you. the normal particle editor opens a default png but does not save it in the folder. that confused me. with the right png it just looks fine. thanks for the help